Copy and pasting wont work in animation. Not even duplicate


I have duplicated, copy and pasted (ctrl C and V and It wont work at all. I have even restarted my program mutiple times. Am I doing it wrong?
Here is the copy of the blnd file


Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Yes of course! I'll make an edit of that right now

You have only created a keyframe for the X rotation, you need to create a keyframe for Y and Z if you want to keep the same orientation, otherwise it will get the Y and Z rotation of the previous pose:

